# jQuery simple dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a simple dropdown using jQuery which opens on mouse click and closes on mouse click or a click over the document.
I have the following JS code to make that work. Refer to my code at http://jsfiddle.net/4mCsy/1/ .But the code is not working :-

```
var x=0;
if(x==0){
    $(".notification").click(function(){
        $(".drpdwn").css("display","block");
    });
    x=1;

}
if(x==1){
    $(".notification").click(function(){
        $(".drpdwn").css("display","none");
    });
    x=0;

}
```

But, when I change the code to the following(removing the lower portion of the code) (http://jsfiddle.net/4mCsy/2/), the code partly works in just openiing the dropdown. But does not closes (**OBVIOUSLY**):-

```
var x=0;
if(x==0){
    $(".notification").click(function(){
        $(".drpdwn").css("display","block");
    });
    x=1;

}
```

Please tell me where am I going wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".notification").on('click',function(){
  $(".drpdwn").toggle();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4mCsy/5/)**

Updated:

```
<div class="notification">Notification</div>
<div class="drpdwn"></div>
$(".notification").on('click', function () {
    $(".drpdwn").toggle('slow');
});
```

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/4mCsy/15/)

Comment: nice answer..(+1) but, the drop down closes on clicking the drop down itself, which I do not want. Plus, I want the drop down to close on document click

Answer (score 2):

They've made it a little to do this in recent jQuery versions:

[jQuery toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.notification', function() {
    $('.drpdwn').toggle(); 
});
```

If you wish to exclude the dropdown itself, which is toggling because `.drpdwn` is *child* member of `.notification`, you'd have to exclude it from a given condition - I'd prefer doing that from the `event.target`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.notification', function( event ) {
   if ( event.target.className != 'drpdwn' )
       $('.drpdwn').toggle();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4mCsy/24/)**

Otherwise you'd have to separate the two `<div>`'s because as explained previously, they're a member of each other. Thus, the jQuery selector will listen to both `<div>`s when you click `.notification`. To prevent this, restructure your HTML as below:

```
<!-- Notification Click -->
<div class="notification">
    Notification
</div>

<!-- Dropdown Div -->
<div class="drpdwn">
</div>
```

Comment: nice answer..(+1) but, the drop down closes on clicking the drop down itself, which I do not want. Plus, I want the drop down to close on document click

Comment: Edited the answer to exclude the drpdown :)

Comment: @BenLind is there anything else I can help with? :o

Comment: @MackieeE: **+1**  for done without changing markup ie target.event

Answer (score 0):

You are going write as of now you are only specifying that you need to open the dropdown when you click but not close. So, you can use `toggle()` to open and close the dropdown.

```
<div class="notification">Notification</div>
<div class="drpdwn"></div>
$(".notification").on('click',function(){
     $(".drpdwn").toggle('blind', 'options', 500 );
});
```

Here's the link for it : http://jsfiddle.net/coolshivster/4mCsy/25/